# How do I prevent new network requests made for already-retrieved images on tab change, form change etc. in React/React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching, browser-cache

When I change something on my page such as checking radio buttons or switching tabs, new network requests to retrieve images are sent from the browser. I've noticed this with a couple of websites I've made, but there should never be another request; I'm not performing a `fetch` on changing these values in the frontend. I don't see why the images should be requested again.

I've attached a gif showing it happening in an app I'm making with React Native, although I've seen it in my React projects too. You can see the images flicker as I switch tabs and the network calls in devtools on the right, and I'm also worried about the performance impact.

How can I prevent this from happening?

For context the data flow in my app is as follows:

1. In `App.tsx` render `MainStackNavigator` component.
2. In `MainStackNavigator` call firebase to retrieve data (including images). Store that data in `Context`.
3. In `Home.tsx` render the `Tabs` component, but also create an array containing the tabs data, namely the name of the component to render and the component itself.
4. In tabs render content based on selected tab.

Home.tsx

```
export const Home = (): ReactNode => {
  const scenes = [
    {
      key: "first",
      component: EnglishBreakfastHome,
    },
    {
      key: "second",
      component: SecondRoute,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View flex={1}>
      <Tabs scenes={scenes} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Tabs.tsx

```
export const Tabs = ({ scenes }: TabsProps): ReactNode => {  
  const renderScenes = useMemo(() =>
    scenes.reduce((map, scene) => {
      map[scene.key] = scene.component;
      return map;
    }, {})
  );

  const renderScene = SceneMap(renderScenes);

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [routes] = useState([
    { key: "first", title: "Breakfast" },
    { key: "second", title: "Herbal" },
  ]);

  const renderTabBar = ({ navigationState, position }: TabViewProps) => {
    const inputRange = navigationState.routes.map((_, i) => i);
    return (
      <Box flexDirection="row">
        {navigationState.routes.map((route, i) => {
          const opacity = position.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: inputRange.map((inputIndex) =>
              inputIndex === i ? 1 : 0.5
            ),
          });

          return (
            // Tab boxes and styling
          );
        })}
      </Box>
    );
  };

  return (
    <TabView // using react-native-tab-view
      style={{ flexBasis: 0 }}
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Gif of my app and network reqs in devtools]

Answer (score 0):

Look into something like [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image). It is even [recommended](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#use-cached-optimized-images) by the react-native docs.

It handles cashing of images. From the docs:

```
const YourImage = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here wasn't image caching at all, it was state management.

I made a call to a db to retrieve images, and then stored that array of images in `AppContext` which wrapped the whole app. Then, everytime I changed state at all, I ran into this problem because the app was being re-rendered. There were two things I did to remove this problem:

1. Separate `Context` into separate stores rather than just using a single global state object. I created a `ContentContext` that contained all the images so that state was kept separate from other state changes and, therefore, re-renders weren't triggered.
2. I made use of `useMemo`, and re-wrote the cards (that you can see in the image) to only change when the main images data array changed. This means that, regardless of changes to other state variables, that component will not need to re-render until the images array changes.

Either of the two solutions should work on their own, but I used both just to be safe.